# How do I add to or change a stack's tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an existing AWS CloudFormation stack, and I would like to add an additional tag to the stack. I went through the "Update Stack" UI steps, but didn't see anything that allows me to update the tag.

Is it possible to add a tag to an existing tag, and if so, how?

Answer (score 6):

You can update the tags on an existing stack by running update-stack for the aws cli:

```
$ aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name myStack --template-body file://myCloudformationTemplate.yaml --tags='[{"Key": "Author","Value": "Me"}, {"Key": "Project", "Value": "Foo"}]'
```

Comment: This will override the existing tags so be sure to get the old tags from `describe-stacks` if you want to do an update or add.

Answer (score 1):

[Creating a stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html)
provides you a way to add a tag, but [Updating a stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateStack.html) does not have that option. Because of this limitation [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2032) has no way to update the tag of CF stack.

Comment: It seems you can update tags now, from the linked document:
Key-value pairs to associate with this stack. AWS CloudFormation also propagates these tags to supported resources in the stack. You can specify a maximum number of 50 tags.

Answer (score 0):

setting tags for CloudFormation Stack "CURRENTLLY" is possible only when you create the stack, you have 2 options here : 1) tag your resources manually. 2) create a new stack with the new tags and delete the old one.